# SQL GROUP BY - not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, firebird

I am trying to summarize data on a Firebird database. The result is the error in the headline. I don't find any error why group by does not work with this data

Table

| Online | BELEGART | NETTO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | AU | 10,00 |
| 11111 | MS | 20,00 |
| 22222 | AU | 10,00 |
| 22222 | MS | 40,00 |
| 33333 | AU | 30,00 |
| 44444 | MS | 35,00 |

The result should be this

| Online | BELEGART_AU | NETTO_AU | BELEGART_MS | NETTO_MS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | AU | 10,00 | MS | 20,00 |
| 22222 | AU | 10,00 | MS | 40,00 |
| 33333 | AU | 30,00 |  |  |
| 44444 |  |  | MS | 35,00 |

This is my code

```sql
Select 
   B.ONLINE 
    ,case when B.BELEGART = 'AU' then B.BELEGART end as BELEGART_AU        
    ,case when B.BELEGART = 'AU' then B.NETTO end as NETTO_AU
    ,case when B.BELEGART = 'MS' then B.BELEGART end as BELEGART_MS        
    ,case when B.BELEGART = 'MS' then B.NETTO end as NETTO_MS
FROM BELEG B
WHERE
    B.BELEGART in ('AU','MS')
GROUP BY B.ONLINE
```

I tried with aggregates like sum, max and list.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the mistake in my simple code the whole day. Maybe my own solution will help someone.

```sql
Select 
B.ONLINE
,max(case when B.BELEGART = 'AU' then B.BELEGART end) as BELEGART_AU
,sum(case when B.BELEGART = 'AU' then B.NETTO end) NETTO_AU
,max(case when B.BELEGART = 'MS' then B.BELEGART end) as BELEGART_MS  
,sum(case when B.BELEGART = 'MS' then B.NETTO end) NETTO_MS
FROM BELEG 
GROUP BY B.ONLINE
```